# How can I simplify this MySQL query when using a UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, union

This query works.. for querying 50 mysql databases at once and returning the most recent 10 results, but..  is there a way to not query the entire database of each state (only 4 states listed in my example), just get the top 10 (by timeStamp desc) and make this query far more efficient?

```
$query = "    
SELECT imgURLThumb, timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
FROM (
  SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title FROM db_washington.md_postings UNION ALL 
  SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title FROM db_westvirginia.md_postings UNION ALL 
  SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title FROM db_wisconsin.md_postings UNION ALL 
  SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title FROM db_wyoming.md_postings 

) allposts where imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png' order by timeStamp DESC LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redesign your database so that all the postings are in a single database to make this query much easier to write. It looks like a bad design to have a database for each state. You should instead have a single table `md_postings` for *all* postings, where one of the fields is `State`.

If that's not possible then I think you have a trade-off:

- Concise and readable SQL or
- Good performance.

If you want better performance try this:

```
SELECT imgURLThumb, timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
FROM (
    (SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
    FROM db_washington.md_postings
    WHERE imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png'
    ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
    LIMIT 10)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
    FROM db_westvirginia.md_postings
    WHERE imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png'
    ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
    LIMIT 10)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
    FROM db_wisconsin.md_postings
    WHERE imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png'
    ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
    LIMIT 10)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT imgURLThumb,timeStamp, title2, state, postId, title
    FROM db_wyoming.md_postings
    WHERE imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png'
    ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
    LIMIT 10)
) AS allposts
WHERE imgURLThumb <> 'images/nopicture.png'
ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @John: Sorry I missed some parentheses.

Comment: Those parens did the trick!  Thanks, John!  I do plan on merging all into 1 db.  It's on my "to-do" list.  Thanks again for the help!  The query really zips now!